# Pokemon Go login issues after update

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I downloaded the July 30th update for Pokemon Go and when I open the app I'm prompted to login, **But once I login, it redirects me to this page on Cookies:**:

[image: Google Account login page] [image: Google's 'Enabling cookies' menu]

If I click "**Done**" in the top left, it prompts me to login again! I've tried reinstalling the game, restarting my phone, etc. I can't much enable Cookies on the inline Safari browser. It doesn't make sense, and cookies are on in Safari (because I don't use Safari and they're enabled by default).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I did that worked for me. Might not even need to do what I did...

1. Iphone > Settings > Safari > Block Cookies > Always Allow
2. Open Safari > Gmail.com > Logon with your gmail account > Open
   Pokemon Go

[More information about this issue from niantic itself](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/224047008)

Comment: Perfect, that worked. I guess I had to be signed in on Safari then try it. Cookies were on 'Allow from current site' so I still don't understand that, but hey, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and the fix didn't help me either.  But then I restarted my phone after resetting the cookies in settings and then logged into google in safari and then pokemon go, and then it seemed to work.

Comment: Even after a reset this isn't working for me. Bummer.

Comment: If none of the above resolve the issue, after authenticating and being redirected to the google home screen, click the safari icon on the bottom right. It will open the page in safari and ask if you want to resubmit the form. Hit yes and it will as if you want to open the page in pokemon go. Hit yes and it will load you into the game. Finally!