# Is it possible to transfer your Pokemon Go account to Trainer Club?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am [having problems](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278248/pokemon-go-login-issues-after-update) with the Google login for Pokemon Go. Is there any way, be it contacting support or through Trainer Club, to either link my Google account to a new Trainer Club account or transfer my account to a Trainer Club account?

It seems like a better idea to have a Trainer Club account, so if there are Google login problems it won't matter.

Does anyone know if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can now link PTC, Google, and Facebook accounts:
[From the FAQ](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/227084307):

> If you would like to use a different login method, you can link another login provider to your account. [Learn more.](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000633307)
>
> In Map View, tap the Main Menu 
>   At the top right, tap Settings 
>   Under the Account section, select the “Not Linked” checkbox next to the login provider you would like to connect.
>   Follow the prompts to link your account. Once your account is linked, you can use that login provider to sign into your Pokémon GO account.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this allows for what the OP was asking. As of this posting, I'm only seeing a way to link to your Google or Facebook accounts, nothing about Pokemon Trainer. I'll be contacting support about the same issue. (Wanting to unlink my Google login.)

Comment: @livingtech, were you able to do the link from PTC to another type?

Comment: No, I wanted to unlink my google account. Never got a response from support.

Answer (score 8):

From the [Pokemon Go FAQ](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/227084307)

> "I would like to switch my login method"
>
> At this time, you cannot transfer your account’s login method from a Google Account to Pokémon Trainer Club or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Niantic *might* be able to do it if you [get in touch with them](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com), but I wouldn't hold my breath. Otherwise, there's no way to do it.

You can switch from logging in with Google to Pokemon Trainer Club (or vice-versa), but they are separate accounts, so you can't transfer any progress this way.

Comment: This feature has been added, see my new answer.