# i have two accounts can i sync them?

Tags: pokemon-go

My son asked me to make a Pokemon trainer club account so he can play Pokemon go, when the game fist launched.But I count because the servers were always down. so i was able to log in with my google account and been playing ever since. Just a few days ago i was able to make an account with Pokemon trainer club but i have to start all over again. Is there any way to sync my two accounts so i can continue at the level I'm at?

Comment: [Get in touch with them](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us) from [Is it possible to transfer your Pokemon Go account to Trainer Club?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/278282/126536)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

You must continue to use your Google login if you want the progress associated with that account.

You could *try* to [contact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/278282/125786) them.