# Can't log-in to Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

I just got the new update, and the app logged me out. 
I tried logging in with Google, but when I log in, it redirects me to the Google homepage. I click done and all it does is prompt me to log in again. I do again and it redirects me to Google again. I click done and this time, it shows a white screen.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm facing the same issue, and it *doesn't* appear to be the same as in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278248/pokemon-go-login-issues-after-update)